# How can I split two digit into two different strings?

Tags: java

I have month in, which contains a value such as `12`. I am trying to split it into two different strings e.g. a=1 and b=2. How do I do this?

Comment: What type is your month value to begin with? `int`?

Comment: Date DATE_OF_REPORT= rs1.getDate("DATE_OF_REPORT");
  DateFormat month = new SimpleDateFormat("MM");
  DateFormat date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd");
  DateFormat year = new SimpleDateFormat("yy");

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do this.

```
// Working with Strings ------
String str = "12";

// Get char array
char[] chars = str.toCharArray();

// Two substrings
String firstStr = str.substring(0,1);
String secondStr = str.substring(1,2);

// Working with ints ---------
int i = 12;

int firstInt = i / 10;   // Divide
int secondInt = i % 10;  // Modulo
```

Comment: i tried all the way if i try this way so output like firstSter=j and secondStr=a  i need number 1 and 2

Comment: Date DATE_OF_REPORT= rs1.getDate("DATE_OF_REPORT"); DateFormat month = new SimpleDateFormat("MM");

Answer (score 0):

Use `String.charAt(index)` method to return a character and use `Character.toString(char)` to convert it to `String`.

Comment: its not work giving error or wrong outputDate DATE_OF_REPORT= rs1.getDate("DATE_OF_REPORT"); DateFormat month = new SimpleDateFormat("MM");

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method substring of class String.

There is the documentation: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int, int)

The algorithm is not complex ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String input = "12";
System.out.println(input.charAt(0)); // gives '1'
System.out.println(input.charAt(1)); // gives '2'
```

Furthermore, if you wish to have '1' and '2' as Strings (not as chars), you can do this :

```
String firstDigit = input.charAt(0) + "";
String secondDigit = input.charAt(1) + "";
```

Good luck !

Konstantin

**EDIT**: Lets assume that 'month' is variable of type java.util.Date. Then:

```
String monthToString = new SimpleDateFormat("MM").format(month);
String firstDigit = monthToString.charAt(0) + "";
String secondDigit = monthToString.charAt(1) + "";
```

Comment: System.out.println("..."+month.toString().charAt(0));
  System.out.println("..."+month.toString().charAt(1));
  its give j.. and a..

Comment: It depends on the type of the 'month' variable. If it is java.util.Date, then you have to use this : new SimpleDateFormat("MM").format(month).charAt(0) for the first character of the month.

I've edited my explanation, so try it out. Now it should work fine.

Comment: Can you tell me what's the type of the variable 'month' ?

Comment: Date DATE_OF_REPORT= rs1.getDate("DATE_OF_REPORT");
  DateFormat month = new SimpleDateFormat("MM");

Comment: java.util.Date or java.sql.Date ... or some other type of Date ? If it is java.util.Date or java.sql.Date, it works here, so I assume that rs1.getDate(..) returns some other type...

Answer (score 0):

Use :

```
 str.split("\\w.+")
```

For Example :

```
 String[] parts = "12".split("\\w.+");
 String a = parts[0]
 Strign b = parts[1]
```

You can Take a look here

http://www.roseindia.net/regularexpressions/splitting-string.shtml

Comment: i tried from all this way its giving error or wrong type please help me Date DATE_OF_REPORT= rs1.getDate("DATE_OF_REPORT"); DateFormat month = new SimpleDateFormat("MM");

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way might be to convert it to a String and then use charAt() to read the characters one by one.

Sounds like a homework question :)

Comment: i tried all the way even its giving error or wrong outputDate DATE_OF_REPORT= rs1.getDate("DATE_OF_REPORT"); DateFormat month = new SimpleDateFormat("MM");

Comment: i tried all the way to do this its giving error or wrong output Date DATE_OF_REPORT= rs1.getDate("DATE_OF_REPORT"); DateFormat month = new SimpleDateFormat("MM");

Answer (score 0):

```
String x = "12";
String[] x_arr= x.split("");
```

your chars will be located in
    x[1]
    x[2]
and eventually you can go on with the index if you passed a longer string (like a year).
Just avoid x[0] because it is an empty string.

Comment: i tried that way here is my date format i need to from this please can you help me Date DATE_OF_REPORT= rs1.getDate("DATE_OF_REPORT"); DateFormat month = new SimpleDateFormat("MM");

Comment: you are uncomprensible, my friend. i am sorry

Answer (score 0):

`String splits[] = "12".split("@?")` would work.

Comment: Date DATE_OF_REPORT= rs1.getDate("DATE_OF_REPORT"); DateFormat month = new SimpleDateFormat("MM");

Comment: It is very clear your question is worded poorly. You may want to rephrase it heavily.